# Puzzle in Martin Gardner book

Tags: pr.probability

What is the official name of this problem? Martin Gardner gives introduction in his book "Math circus". The problem belongs to 1D random walk. What can be read to gain deep insight into this problem? Or other useful resources.

> We can complicate matters by allowing transition probabilities
>   to vary from 1/2 and by allowing steps longer than one
>   unit. Consider the following curious paradox first called to my 
>   attention (in betting terms) by Enn Norak, a Canadian mathematician.
>   A walker starts 100 steps to the right of 0 on a line
>   that has no barriers. Instead of a coin a packet
>   of 10 playing cards-five red and five black-is used as a randomizer.
>   The cards are shuffled and spread face down and any
>   card is selected. After its color is noted it is discarded. If it is red, the walker steps to the right: if black, he steps to the left.
>   This continues until all 10 cards have been taken. (The transition
>   probability varies with each step. It is 1/2 only when there
>   is an equal mixture of red and black cards before the draw.)
>   The walk differs also from walks discussed above in that before
>   each card is noted the walker chooses the length (which need
>   not be integral) of his next step.
>   Assume that the walker adopts the following halving strategy
>   in choosing step lengths. After each card is noted he takes a step
>   (left or right) equal to exactly half of his distance from 0. His
>   first step is 100/2 = 50 units. If the card is red, he goes to the
>   150 mark. His next step will then be 150/2 = 75. If the first
>   card drawn is black, he goes left to the 50 mark, and so his next
>   step will be 50/2 = 25. He continues in this manner until the
>   tenth card is noted. Will he then be to the right or to the left of
>   the 100 mark where he began the walk?
>   The answer is that he is sure to be to the left. This may not
>   be very surprising, but it is surely astonishing that, regardless 
>   of the order in which the cards are drawn, he will end the walk at 
>   exactly the same spot.

Comment: Hi columbus: I have fixed some formatting.  I think that you had intended a horizontal line between your question and the quote, but it had formatted in some strange way to make the question very large, which gave the impression of shouting.  I've switched what I think is a quote from Gardner into blockquote formatting.  If I have messed something up, you can revert the changes.

Comment: So... on black cards his distance from 0 is multiplied by $\frac 12$, and on red cards it's multiplied by $\frac 32$. There are 5 of each, so after 10 steps his distance from 0 has been multiplied by $\frac {3^5}{2^{10}}$, regardless of order. There doesn't seem to be much more to it than that, or am I missing something? If you take logs, it turns back into a regular random walk, and you know how many total steps are taken each way.

Comment: That said, many of Gardner's puzzles do not extend to gain deep insight, so I don't know if you'll find what you're looking for.  I'm not an expert on random walks.

Comment: The name I'd give it is "multiplication is commutative".

Comment: The question seems to presuppose that such puzzles have official names.  Rather few have names at all, and I know of no way for a name to become "official".

Comment: @Robert Israel: Maybe "multiplication is commutative" can serve as the deep insight (as well as the name).

Comment: I don't see much of a future in Robert Israel's becoming a puzzle writer.  (If he shouts spoilers out in theatres. I don't think I'll go to the movies with him either.)  Gerhard "Multiplication Can Also Be Associative" Paseman, 2011.07.13 

Comment: Gerhard, hadn't Vaughn already given the explanation before Robert Israel? Where's the harm in what Robert wrote? 

Comment: I don't think Gerhard is objecting to the presence of Robert's comment here but to the idea of using "multiplication is commutative" as the *name* of the puzzle.  Standard practice is that the name of a puzzle should not give away the answer.  

Comment: Andreas is right.  However, I also think a better hint would be that multiplication is both commutative and associative.  And make for a lousier puzzle name. Also, no disrespect intended, hypothetical or otherwise, for Prof. Israel.  I am quite comfortable with him and his history of giving answers.  Gerhard "Email Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.13

Comment: Now that we've dispensed with the deep insight of logarithmic random walks, we are left with the question of an official name.  I think this question may find a happier home elsewhere on the internet, e.g., one of the sites listed in the FAQ.

Comment: The consensus seems to be that the problem has no offical name and there is no deep insight to be had, so I have voted to close. 

Comment: A nontrivial variation is that you choose what fraction of your bankroll to bet on whether the next card is red or black. As long as you bet on the favored side (if any), and you choose to bet everything if only one color is left in the deck, then your expected bankroll does not depend on your other choices. Also, there is a strategy so that you end up with the same amount regardless of the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, multiplication is commutative, but there is more to it than that. While being reasonably easy, this puzzle suggests variations in ways that the equation $x\cdot y = y\cdot x$ doesn't.

In his wonderful paper Games People Don't Play, http://www.teorver.ru/newkatalog/1193689162.pdf, Peter Winkler describes essentially the same game as ``Next card color betting'' (a bit of googling also turns up http://www.maxdama.com/?p=137 and http://www.dartblog.com/data/2008/08/007950.php). But there the player, Victor, wants to end up as far to the right as possible (increasing his bankroll). It turns out that there is a strategy that guarantees him to end up with $2^{10}/\binom{10}{5} = 256/63$ times his initial bankroll, or about 406 steps to the right of the origin.

This is a game that children can understand, but if we pursue the analysis, it doesn't stop until we have developed, besides insights into hedging strategies, a good deal of nontrivial mathematics including information theory (the amount of information Victor has about the red-black sequence dictates exactly how much money he will ideally make by betting), the Wallis product formula (showing that his final bankroll is asymptotically $\sqrt{\pi n}$ for a deck of $n$ red and $n$ black cards), and even the central limit theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know variation of this problem when the exact number of cards is unknown?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another expression of the same trivial puzzle. I buy some shares for $1000.  In five of the next ten weeks (I'm not saying which five), their price rises by 50%; in the other five, it falls by 50%. What are my shares now worth?